# Realm sync across the clients

Tags: ios, database, synchronization, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I searched across many threads and issues but I doesn't found the answer.
When I use the `Realm Objects Server` and the clients connects to the server, the whole DB is synced across all the clients?

In other words, if I have a public DB with millions of objects, relations, etc all the clients have a copy of the whole DB on their devices?

I'll need `Realm` sync feature but I don't know how to sync occurs. Is the sync incremental? Every user has the objects that device needs to make queries?

My app will increment the size every hour, and the sync feature of the `Realm` is perfect for me, but I have doubts about the size of DB over the time and how clients sync a lot of data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, yes. Public Realms are synchronized in their entirety to every client's device. The entire list will initially be downloaded when the client's device connects for the first time, and from that point on, any additional changes will be synchronized at the time they are made on the server.

That being said, all Realm files are compacted (ie, all empty allocated space is removed and all strings are condensed), and then compressed with gzip before being downloaded to the client, so as long as the public Realm doesn't contain large binary blobs, even very large files should come down quite quickly.

It's on the roadmap to add partial replication to the Realm Mobile Platform. This will allow only portions of a single Realm file to be synchronized to specific clients. However there are no concrete plans for when this will be released.

For the time being, the easiest thing to do would be to maintain the master list of data on the server, and copy only the desired data to each user's private Realm. However since this would require custom logic to be executed on the server, it would require the [Professional](https://realm.io/pricing/realm-professional-edition/) or Enterprise editions of the Realm Mobile Platform.

Comment: Thanks! I think that the main problems will come after 1-2 year of data retrieval and the size of DB increase too much. I will try with a test instance with a lot of data.

Comment: is there any way to calculate the expected size of DB?

Comment: No worries! Sadly not at the moment. The size can vary greatly depending on the data types of its content. Good luck! If the tests don't go as you expect, feel free to file an issue on the Realm GitHub so we can examine it in detail.

Comment: I tried with 210000 random string objects and the disk size was 90Mb. When the user download for first time, the DB is compressed right?

Comment: Yep! If you want to simulate the actual transmission size, open the Realm file in the Realm Browswer, export it as a compacted Realm, and then compress it to a zip file.